# ¿Cómo serializar un formulario en Javascript, sin jQuery ni otras librerías externas?

Tags: javascript

En jQuery es relativamente fácil serializar todos los elementos de un formulario usando `serialize`.

He estado buscando si había algún equivalente en Javascript puro, pero no lo encuentro. Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de serializar un formulario de forma fácil.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```js
$("#btnSerialize").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var frmData = $("#frmTest").serialize();
  console.log(frmData);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmTest">
  <input type="text" name="ibxNombre" value="Test" id="ibxNombre" placeholder="Escriba su nombre" />
  <br />

  <select name="cbxOpciones">
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
  </select>


  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkSi" value="1" checked />
  <label for="chkSi">Sí</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkNO" value="0" />
  <label for="chkNo">No</label>

  <br /><br />
  <button id="btnSerialize">Serializar</button>
  <br>

</form>
```

He visto que podría usar `FormData` y hacer `append` de los elementos del formulario. Pero los ejemplos de MDN muestran cómo hacer `append`  *a mano*  de cada elemento, lo cual no es práctico, sobre todo en formularios largos. Lo que busco es alguna función que trabaje igual que `serialize` de jQuery. ¿Existe en Javascript puro?

Comment: aqui lo teneis : http://jsfiddle.net/eftsa93c/

Comment: Probaste mirando el codigo fuente de jQuery? https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez sea más un comentario extendido que una respuesta,

1) Analisis del source del serialize
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js

```
define( [
    "./core",
    "./core/toType",
    "./manipulation/var/rcheckableType",
    "./var/isFunction",
    "./core/init",
    "./traversing", // filter
    "./attributes/prop"
], function( jQuery, toType, rcheckableType, isFunction ) {

"use strict";

var
    rbracket = /\[\]$/,
    rCRLF = /\r?\n/g,
    rsubmitterTypes = /^(?:submit|button|image|reset|file)$/i,
    rsubmittable = /^(?:input|select|textarea|keygen)/i;

function buildParams( prefix, obj, traditional, add ) {
    var name;

    if ( Array.isArray( obj ) ) {

        // Serialize array item.
        jQuery.each( obj, function( i, v ) {
            if ( traditional || rbracket.test( prefix ) ) {

                // Treat each array item as a scalar.
                add( prefix, v );

            } else {

                // Item is non-scalar (array or object), encode its numeric index.
                buildParams(
                    prefix + "[" + ( typeof v === "object" && v != null ? i : "" ) + "]",
                    v,
                    traditional,
                    add
                );
            }
        } );

    } else if ( !traditional && toType( obj ) === "object" ) {

        // Serialize object item.
        for ( name in obj ) {
            buildParams( prefix + "[" + name + "]", obj[ name ], traditional, add );
        }

    } else {

        // Serialize scalar item.
        add( prefix, obj );
    }
}

// Serialize an array of form elements or a set of
// key/values into a query string
jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
    var prefix,
        s = [],
        add = function( key, valueOrFunction ) {

            // If value is a function, invoke it and use its return value
            var value = isFunction( valueOrFunction ) ?
                valueOrFunction() :
                valueOrFunction;

            s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" +
                encodeURIComponent( value == null ? "" : value );
        };

    // If an array was passed in, assume that it is an array of form elements.
    if ( Array.isArray( a ) || ( a.jquery && !jQuery.isPlainObject( a ) ) ) {

        // Serialize the form elements
        jQuery.each( a, function() {
            add( this.name, this.value );
        } );

    } else {

        // If traditional, encode the "old" way (the way 1.3.2 or older
        // did it), otherwise encode params recursively.
        for ( prefix in a ) {
            buildParams( prefix, a[ prefix ], traditional, add );
        }
    }

    // Return the resulting serialization
    return s.join( "&" );
};

jQuery.fn.extend( {
    serialize: function() {
        return jQuery.param( this.serializeArray() );
    },
    serializeArray: function() {
        return this.map( function() {

            // Can add propHook for "elements" to filter or add form elements
            var elements = jQuery.prop( this, "elements" );
            return elements ? jQuery.makeArray( elements ) : this;
        } )
        .filter( function() {
            var type = this.type;

            // Use .is( ":disabled" ) so that fieldset[disabled] works
            return this.name && !jQuery( this ).is( ":disabled" ) &&
                rsubmittable.test( this.nodeName ) && !rsubmitterTypes.test( type ) &&
                ( this.checked || !rcheckableType.test( type ) );
        } )
        .map( function( i, elem ) {
            var val = jQuery( this ).val();

            if ( val == null ) {
                return null;
            }

            if ( Array.isArray( val ) ) {
                return jQuery.map( val, function( val ) {
                    return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
                } );
            }

            return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };
        } ).get();
    }
} );

return jQuery;
} );
```

tiene una lista de elementos "enviadores" y una lista de elementos "enviables"

mapea un array con el par nombre valor de cada elemento "enviable"

filtra los ":disabled"

filtra los tipo chekbox comprobando si estan "checked" además de ser "checkeables"

si el valor es vacío (val==null) no lo agrega

encodifica los saltos de línea como "\r\n"

finalmente usa encodeURIComponent en el key y el val del array y junta todo con un `&`

hay algunos pasos extra por si lo que le mandás es un conjunto/array/lista de forms

Lo que no veo es que reemplaze `%20` (el espacio encodeURIeado) por un `+` que sería el estándar, pero tu fiddle demuestra que se produce automágicamente

Buscando alternativas en github:

2) una implementación bastante parecida a la de jquery pero un poco mas "secuencial" y muy bien documentado cada paso
https://github.com/defunctzombie/form-serialize

```
// get successful control from form and assemble into object
// http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

// types which indicate a submit action and are not successful controls
// these will be ignored
var k_r_submitter = /^(?:submit|button|image|reset|file)$/i;

// node names which could be successful controls
var k_r_success_contrls = /^(?:input|select|textarea|keygen)/i;

// Matches bracket notation.
var brackets = /(\[[^\[\]]*\])/g;

// serializes form fields
// @param form MUST be an HTMLForm element
// @param options is an optional argument to configure the serialization. Default output
// with no options specified is a url encoded string
//    - hash: [true | false] Configure the output type. If true, the output will
//    be a js object.
//    - serializer: [function] Optional serializer function to override the default one.
//    The function takes 3 arguments (result, key, value) and should return new result
//    hash and url encoded str serializers are provided with this module
//    - disabled: [true | false]. If true serialize disabled fields.
//    - empty: [true | false]. If true serialize empty fields
function serialize(form, options) {
    if (typeof options != 'object') {
        options = { hash: !!options };
    }
    else if (options.hash === undefined) {
        options.hash = true;
    }

    var result = (options.hash) ? {} : '';
    var serializer = options.serializer || ((options.hash) ? hash_serializer : str_serialize);

    var elements = form && form.elements ? form.elements : [];

    //Object store each radio and set if it's empty or not
    var radio_store = Object.create(null);

    for (var i=0 ; i<elements.length ; ++i) {
        var element = elements[i];

        // ingore disabled fields
        if ((!options.disabled && element.disabled) || !element.name) {
            continue;
        }
        // ignore anyhting that is not considered a success field
        if (!k_r_success_contrls.test(element.nodeName) ||
            k_r_submitter.test(element.type)) {
            continue;
        }

        var key = element.name;
        var val = element.value;

        // we can't just use element.value for checkboxes cause some browsers lie to us
        // they say "on" for value when the box isn't checked
        if ((element.type === 'checkbox' || element.type === 'radio') && !element.checked) {
            val = undefined;
        }

        // If we want empty elements
        if (options.empty) {
            // for checkbox
            if (element.type === 'checkbox' && !element.checked) {
                val = '';
            }

            // for radio
            if (element.type === 'radio') {
                if (!radio_store[element.name] && !element.checked) {
                    radio_store[element.name] = false;
                }
                else if (element.checked) {
                    radio_store[element.name] = true;
                }
            }

            // if options empty is true, continue only if its radio
            if (val == undefined && element.type == 'radio') {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            // value-less fields are ignored unless options.empty is true
            if (!val) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        // multi select boxes
        if (element.type === 'select-multiple') {
            val = [];

            var selectOptions = element.options;
            var isSelectedOptions = false;
            for (var j=0 ; j<selectOptions.length ; ++j) {
                var option = selectOptions[j];
                var allowedEmpty = options.empty && !option.value;
                var hasValue = (option.value || allowedEmpty);
                if (option.selected && hasValue) {
                    isSelectedOptions = true;

                    // If using a hash serializer be sure to add the
                    // correct notation for an array in the multi-select
                    // context. Here the name attribute on the select element
                    // might be missing the trailing bracket pair. Both names
                    // "foo" and "foo[]" should be arrays.
                    if (options.hash && key.slice(key.length - 2) !== '[]') {
                        result = serializer(result, key + '[]', option.value);
                    }
                    else {
                        result = serializer(result, key, option.value);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Serialize if no selected options and options.empty is true
            if (!isSelectedOptions && options.empty) {
                result = serializer(result, key, '');
            }

            continue;
        }

        result = serializer(result, key, val);
    }

    // Check for all empty radio buttons and serialize them with key=""
    if (options.empty) {
        for (var key in radio_store) {
            if (!radio_store[key]) {
                result = serializer(result, key, '');
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function parse_keys(string) {
    var keys = [];
    var prefix = /^([^\[\]]*)/;
    var children = new RegExp(brackets);
    var match = prefix.exec(string);

    if (match[1]) {
        keys.push(match[1]);
    }

    while ((match = children.exec(string)) !== null) {
        keys.push(match[1]);
    }

    return keys;
}

function hash_assign(result, keys, value) {
    if (keys.length === 0) {
        result = value;
        return result;
    }

    var key = keys.shift();
    var between = key.match(/^\[(.+?)\]$/);

    if (key === '[]') {
        result = result || [];

        if (Array.isArray(result)) {
            result.push(hash_assign(null, keys, value));
        }
        else {
            // This might be the result of bad name attributes like "[][foo]",
            // in this case the original `result` object will already be
            // assigned to an object literal. Rather than coerce the object to
            // an array, or cause an exception the attribute "_values" is
            // assigned as an array.
            result._values = result._values || [];
            result._values.push(hash_assign(null, keys, value));
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Key is an attribute name and can be assigned directly.
    if (!between) {
        result[key] = hash_assign(result[key], keys, value);
    }
    else {
        var string = between[1];
        // +var converts the variable into a number
        // better than parseInt because it doesn't truncate away trailing
        // letters and actually fails if whole thing is not a number
        var index = +string;

        // If the characters between the brackets is not a number it is an
        // attribute name and can be assigned directly.
        if (isNaN(index)) {
            result = result || {};
            result[string] = hash_assign(result[string], keys, value);
        }
        else {
            result = result || [];
            result[index] = hash_assign(result[index], keys, value);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// Object/hash encoding serializer.
function hash_serializer(result, key, value) {
    var matches = key.match(brackets);

    // Has brackets? Use the recursive assignment function to walk the keys,
    // construct any missing objects in the result tree and make the assignment
    // at the end of the chain.
    if (matches) {
        var keys = parse_keys(key);
        hash_assign(result, keys, value);
    }
    else {
        // Non bracket notation can make assignments directly.
        var existing = result[key];

        // If the value has been assigned already (for instance when a radio and
        // a checkbox have the same name attribute) convert the previous value
        // into an array before pushing into it.
        //
        // NOTE: If this requirement were removed all hash creation and
        // assignment could go through `hash_assign`.
        if (existing) {
            if (!Array.isArray(existing)) {
                result[key] = [ existing ];
            }

            result[key].push(value);
        }
        else {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// urlform encoding serializer
function str_serialize(result, key, value) {
    // encode newlines as \r\n cause the html spec says so
    value = value.replace(/(\r)?\n/g, '\r\n');
    value = encodeURIComponent(value);

    // spaces should be '+' rather than '%20'.
    value = value.replace(/%20/g, '+');
    return result + (result ? '&' : '') + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + value;
}

module.exports = serialize;
```

3) otra implementación un poco mas pequeña y secuencial, que no hace el reemplazo del espacio y habría que testear bien con names que incluyan `[]` complejos
https://github.com/riverside/form-serialize

```
/**
 * form-serialize v0.2.1
 *
 * Copyright 2017, Dimitar Ivanov (https://zinoui.com/)
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */
 function serialize(form) {
    if (!form || form.nodeName !== "FORM") {
        return;
    }
    var i, j, q = [];
    for (i = form.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
        if (form.elements[i].name === "") {
            continue;
        }
        switch (form.elements[i].nodeName) {
        case 'INPUT':
            switch (form.elements[i].type) {
            case 'text':
            case 'hidden':
            case 'password':
            case 'button':
            case 'reset':
            case 'submit':
            case 'color':
            case 'date':
            case 'datetime-local':
            case 'email':
            case 'month':
            case 'number':
            case 'range':
            case 'search':
            case 'tel':
            case 'time':
            case 'url':
            case 'week':
                q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                if (form.elements[i].checked) {
                    q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                }
                break;
            case 'file':
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 'TEXTAREA':
            q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
            break;
        case 'SELECT':
            switch (form.elements[i].type) {
            case 'select-one':
                q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                break;
            case 'select-multiple':
                for (j = form.elements[i].options.length - 1; j >= 0; j = j - 1) {
                    if (form.elements[i].options[j].selected) {
                        q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].options[j].value));
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 'BUTTON':
            switch (form.elements[i].type) {
            case 'reset':
            case 'submit':
            case 'button':
                q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return q.join("&");
}
```